# Load Div Content from Another Page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to load a div content from another page(this page is in another project which is running in tomcat all together) with javascript ajax.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/prob-services/clogin#login_page');
xhr.onload = function() {
alert(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr);
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal_dialog");
        modal.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

The problem is when I log `xhr` I see that `responseURL` is until `#`, so ajax takes only `http://localhost:8080/prob-services/clogin` instead of `http://localhost:8080/prob-services/clogin#login_page`.  That's why it loads whole page. 
Is there any way to get only div content without JQuery?

Comment: No, you'll have to load the whole page and then filter the wanted div in your response handler. Or you could set up the server to send just that little part based on a parameter in the url, but that would take longer to code and is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: The hash mark `#` is a fragment identifier which is only interpeted by the client. You'll need to filter the content on the client side or switch to a request variable like `http://localhost:8080/prob-services/clogin?page=login_page`

Comment: How can I filter it?

Comment: You can either either template out the div into its own page, then just load that via this request, or an iframe.  Or you can use some type of web scraper to do what you want.

Comment: To do the html filtering of the response on the client side, you can use regex. Let's say the content you're looking for is inside a `<a>` tag, it would look like this: `modal.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.match(/<a [^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/)[1];`. But I would recommend you to only send the needed part from the server side or at least use jQuery for the client-side filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to filter the whole page:

Create a dummy hidden DOM element like

```
<div style='display: none' id="loadedHTML"></div>
```

then put the HTML of the whole page you received from the server into it:

```
document.getElementById('loadedHTML').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

now you can search the html inside this component. Say the part you want to is in a div called "MyDiv" inside the page:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal_dialog");
modal.innerHTML = document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML;
```

fell free to ask more if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery `load()` function

```
$('#modal_dialog').css('opacity','1').load('http://localhost:8080/prob-services/clogin',function() { 
    alert():
} );
```